# Pull certificate from Firefox without using Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, certificate

I have a Comodo email certificate installed in Firefox 20, and I've tried (and failed) many times to export the certificate as PKCS12 (error is "Failed to create the PKCS #12 backup file for unknown reasons.").

Since Firefox can't do this job, is there an external tool to do this? Possibly on the command line? I'm on Linux, OpenSUSE 12.3 x64 with KDE 4.10.2.

Answer (score 2):

On openSUSE you have access to the package **mozilla-nss-tools**. Install it and use the tools **certutil** and **p12util** to export a certificate like:

- find the nickname of your cert using

  ```
  certutil -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/YOUR_PROFILE -L
  ```
- export the cert as P12 with

  ```
  pk12util -o cert.p12 -n "NICKNAME" -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/YOUR_PROFILE
  ```